# Remove items from Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection where Key contains string

Tags: vb.net, collections

I have a `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` where they keys are

```
"123,A"
"123,B"
```

Is there a way to remove all keys where they begin with 123?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looping, I doubt it.  The .Remove() method only accepts a single key as an argument, nothing like a wildcard sort of thing.

Comment: I did it in a backwards loop and removed by index